# double minus double giving precision problems

Tags: c#, double, precision

I have come across a precision issue with double in .NET I thought this only applied to floats but now I see that double is a float.

```
double test = 278.97 - 90.46;
Debug.WriteLine(test) //188.51000000000005

//correct answer is 188.51
```

What is the correct way to handle this? Round? Lop off the unneeded decimal places?

Comment: What do You use those doubles for? If for monetary values for example You have to use other type.

Comment: In that case listen to Michael. Doubles will bite You.

Comment: No, actually `Debug.WriteLine(test)` will write 188.51. To reproduce your output, use `Debug.WriteLine("{0:R}", test)`. The default is to show only 15 significant figures, to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) data type.  "The Decimal value type is appropriate for financial calculations requiring large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors."

Comment: +1 If you're doing financial stuff, you *really* need to be using `decimal`.

Comment: Decimal is the correct data type you should be using for financial calculations. It does not eliminate the need for rounding but minimizes errors due to rounding.

Answer (score 5):

This happens in many languages and stems from the fact that we cannot usually store doubles or floats precisely in digital hardware. For a detailed explanation of how doubles, floats, and all other floating point values are often stored, look at the various IEEE specs described on wikipedia. For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision

Of course there are other formats, such as fixed-point format. But this imprecision is in most languages, and why you often need to use epsilon tests instead of equality tests when using doubles in conditionals (i.e. abs(x - y) <= 0.0001 instead of x == y).

How you deal with this imprecision is up to you, and depends on your application.