# Dealing with Doubles imprecision other than using Decimals

Tags: .net, types, double

I'm having the doubles imprecision problem with the common mathematical operations. It's the one where a simple addition would append a `00000000x` to my double.

I've read from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741903/c-4-double-minus-double-giving-precision-problems) that decimals should be used instead.

But the app I'm using this for is statistics related and performance is an issue. I've read somewhere that Decimals degrade performance by a lot in the long run.

Are there any reasonable alternatives/approaches that you could do to avoid imprecision without using the Decimal datatype?

Comment: When has statistics ever been precise?

Comment: I just need up to 4 decimal places actually, but I've had some trouble rendering some elements to a graph because of those teeeny inconsistencies.

Comment: I don't think you can do something other than using Decimal instead. Maybe if you explain the rendering problems you encounter we could find a solution.

Comment: Ahhh.. Just thought that there would be another solution.  Anyway, I found a workaround for it.  I was using a for loop to iterate over points and the last one's rendering keeps getting skipped at random intervals because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round to the desired number of decimal places when you ultimately display or store the result as a string after doing all of your calculations.

For example, use the following for 4 decimal places:

```
double d = ___;
string s = String.Format(
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "{0:0.0000}", d);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Be aware that this does not mean you will get the same result as if you did it with pencil-and-paper, or with a handheld calculator, or with unlimited precision math. Nor does it mean that the displayed result is correct +/-0.00005 (for the above example): there can be accumulated approximation errors from intermediate calculations.

The following shows how to accomplish something similiar with scientific notation:

```
string s = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "{0:0.0000E0}", d);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx for more information on custom numeric format strings.

If you are not interested in actually displaying or storing the value as a string, another option is to convert to `Decimal` and round after performing the performance-critical calculations in `double`:

```
Decimal dec = Decimal.Round((Decimal)d, 4);
```

Note that when exact correspondence with pencil-and-paper methods is required, you should use `Decimal` for all steps of the calculation, as there are no base-10 to base-2 conversions and the corresponding approximation error associated with such base conversions. That being said, `Decimal` is not unlimited precision: There are still ways encounter approximation errors, though for the most common use cases (e.g., many kinds of financial calculations) `Decimal` will "just work".