# Why is this simple calculation of two doubles inaccurate?

Tags: c#, double, precision

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# (4): double minus double giving precision problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741903/c-4-double-minus-double-giving-precision-problems)

86.25 - 86.24 = 0.01

generally, I would think the above statement is true right?

However, if I enter this

```
        double a = 86.24;
        double b = 86.25;
        double c = b - a;
```

I find that c = 0.010000000000005116

Why is this?

Comment: i'm asking for WHY it's there, like what is happening behind the scene for it to be giving this?

Answer (score 7):

Floating point numbers (in this case doubles) cannot represent decimal values exactly. I would recommend reading David Goldberg's [**What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic**](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

This applies to all languages that deal with floating point numbers whether it be C#, Java, JavaScript, ... This is essential reading for any developer working with floating point arithmetic.

As VinayC suggests, if you need an exact (and slower) representation, use `System.Decimal` (aka `decimal` in C#) instead.

Comment: Since you mention various programming languages, I must point out that Ada is unique in allowing you to specify the desired precision of your reals (e.g. type Happiness is digits 7 range 0.0 .. 1.0`), and also in allowing fixed precision real values, such as `type Compass_Direction is delta 0.1 0 .. 359.9` which don't vary their precision at all across their range.

Answer (score 1):

Double is incorrect data type for decimal calculations, use Decimal for that. Main reason lies in how double stores the number - its essentially a binary approximation of the decimal number.