# Computations in C# as accurately as with Windows Calculator

Tags: c#

When I do the following double multiplication in C# `100.0 * 1.005` I get `100,49999999999999` as a result. I believe this is because the exact number (or some intermedia result when evaluting the expression) cannot be represented. When I do the same computation in calc.exe I get `100.5` as expected.

Another example is the ninefold incrementation of `0.001` (that is the first time a deviation occurs) so basically `9d * 0.001d = 0,0090000000000000011`. When I do the same computation in calc.exe I get `0.009` as expected.

Now one can argue, that I should choose decimal instead. But with decimal I get the problem with other computations for example with `((1M / 3M) * 3M) = 0,9999999999999999999999999999` while calc.exe says `1`.

With calc.exe I can divide 1 by 3 several times until some real small number and then multiply with 3 again as many several times and then I reach exacty `1`. I therefore suspect, that calc.exe computes internally with fractions, but obviously with real big ones, because it computes

```
(677605234775492641 / 116759166847407000) + (932737194383944703 / 2451942503795547000)
```

where the common denominator is -3422539506717149376 (an overflow occured) when doing a long computation, so it must be at least ulong. Does anybody know how computation in calc.exe is implemented? Is this implementation made somewhere public for reuse?

Comment: What type are you casting to for your numbers?

Comment: Microsoft was getting complaints about their old version producing 9,999... so they switched to another computation engine that doesn't lose any digits.  So 1,234 x 4,567 has a result with 6 digits in the fraction.  And uses base 10 instead of base 2, like System.Decimal.  But it is only partial, transcendental functions don't use the expanded range.  Such an engine is both slow and requires a lot of storage.  Doesn't matter to calc.exe because it runs at human-time, a C# program runs at processor-time.  You'll have to go shopping.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Sorry, I don't understand. Please clarify.

Comment: Are you using decimal, double,float etc.  For example, double has a limit to the storage bits that impacts the calculation capability.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx  With a double you WILL experience the issues you describe at some point and this is one reason you should not use it for some calculations.  THIS might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741903/c-sharp-4-double-minus-double-giving-precision-problems

Comment: I have added `d` and `M` in my code above to emphasize to which data type the examples refer to. Our code should be as fast as possible, so double is a better choice than decimal.

Comment: You should read the specification (download from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) and understand the impact of the precision and number of bits used for each.  IF you want to truly emulate calc you should consider rounding, possibly at each step of the formula.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: calc uses an arbitrary-precision engine for algorithmic operations. Rounding at every step actually does the *opposite* of giving you more precision.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040525-00/?p=39193), `calc` uses an arbitrary-precision engine for its calculations, while `double` is standard IEEE-754 arithmetic, and `decimal` is also floating-point arithmetic, just in decimal, which, as you point out, has the same problems, just in another base.

You can try finding such an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library for C# and use it, e.g. [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PeterO.Numbers) (no idea whether it's good; was the first result). The one inside `calc` is not available as an API, so you cannot use it.

Another point is that when you round the result to a certain number of places (less than 15), you'd also get the intuitively "correct" result in a lot of cases. C# already does some rounding to hide the exact value of a `double` from you (where `0.3` is definitely not exactly `0.3`, but probably something like `0.30000000000000004`). By reducing the number of digits you display you lessen the occurrence of such very small differences from the correct value.

Comment: "The one inside calc is not available as an API, so you cannot use it." - The Windows Calculator is open source now: https://github.com/microsoft/calculator Is its API available now? I don't use windows 10 so I can't build the code to test it.