# Double to Byte type conversion error

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, double, byte

When performing conversion from `byte` to `double` by mathematical operations I've got expected result.
Performing the same mathematical operations to reverse the changes in value, results in correct value as long as I keep `double` type.
But when at the end I converts `double` result back to `byte` value the conversion results is incorrect by 1.

This is the case only for some `byte` values.

Exact process:

```
byte b = 82;                    Console.WriteLine(b);   // initial byte value
double d = (b / 100.0) + 2.00;  Console.WriteLine(d);   // 82 / 100 -> 0.82 + 2.00 -> 2.82  OK
double dt = d - 2.00;           Console.WriteLine(dt);  // 2.82 - 2.0 -> 0.82               OK
double db = dt * 100.0;         Console.WriteLine(db);  // 0.82 * 100 -> 82  (double)       OK
byte dbb = (byte)db;            Console.WriteLine(dbb); // (byte)82 -> 81    ERROR ERROR ERROR
b = Byte.Parse(db.ToString());  Console.WriteLine(b);   // 82 -> "82" and to byte           OK
```

Why it is happening?
The `double` result does not have any values after comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you debug your code you will see what is going on:

```
double d = (b / 100.0) + 2.00; Console.WriteLine(d)// => d = 2.82
double dt = d - 2.00; Console.WriteLine(dt) // => dt = 0.81999999999999984
double db = dt * 100.0; Console.WriteLine(db) // => db = 81.999999999999986
byte dbb = (byte)db; Console.WriteLine(dbb)  //=> dbb = 81, because Byte is cut off after the ","
```

If you use *decimal* instead of *double* it will work out.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741903/c-sharp-4-double-minus-double-giving-precision-problems

To make it complete:

```
decimal d = (b / 100.0m) + 2.00m; Console.WriteLine(d); 
decimal dt = d - 2.00m; Console.WriteLine(dt);  
decimal db = dt * (decimal)100.0; Console.WriteLine(db);  
byte dbb = (byte)db; Console.WriteLine(dbb);
```

You can either cast (decimal) or use the "m" behind the value.

Comment: I gave you a link to another Topic on stackoverflow - this will explain it a little more in detail - decimal will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `byte dbb = (byte)db;` use explicit rounding with `byte dbb = (byte)Math.Round(db);`.